# Intranet & Extranet in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, extranet, intranet, multi-tenancy, multiple-farms

In my new company we are moving to SharePoint 2013 in a few months, we currently have a SharePoint 2010 setup but nothing will be migrated to the new environment.

I have been asked to provide a topology that will encompass an intranet, extranet and internet sites.

I have setup extranets before in SharePoint 2010 and I have used just one farm to do that but in this scenario i am thinking that two farms would be best. The reason for this is that on the extranet farm it will be split to allow access to various different partner companies with some aspects being completely anonymous.

I will be exposing the intranet for remote worker but i'm thinking that the extranet will grow and it may be easier to manage if it was a separate farm.

I'm wondering if anyone has had experience in setting this type of scenario up i.e. one farm for intranet and one farm for extranet/internet usage and if anyone has done this type of thing in SharePoint 2013?

One other aspect i have been considering for the extranet is Multi Tenancy but i'm not sure if that would be overkill.....I guess it's on the off chance we have a client that wants to connect their AD to the site.

Thanks
Ginge